# There is any way to block specific apps on snap or flatpak so these can't be installed on my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, snap, flatpak

I want to prevent the installation of some really distracting apps on my computer.
I can do this on Apt by modifying a configuration file.
But I haven't managed to do the same on Snap or Flatpak.
I need either one of those stores to install some applications since some applications I use have dependencies problems.
I tried to search an answer on the store documentation but I didn't found anything. I'm not an expert on this area so any help is welcome.

Comment: One possibility is to block **all** snap & flatpak applications. But this would probably require you to stop using Ubuntu.

Comment: I considered the idea of blocking snap and flatpak but I have some software that cause severe dependencies problems when using apt. So I need at least one store available. I can use other distros like Manjaro but I don't know how to block apps there.

Comment: For SNAP there is only one store possible and it is owned by Canonical (Ubuntu). You can pin specific packages with apt - but this seems unlikely to be of any help in this case.

Comment: I'm curious. The way you can block an app on apt is by giving it a priority of -1 on the upgrade configuration. I have the feeling something like that should be possible on snap or flatpak and if not I'm going to ask if they can add that feature.

Comment: Won't unnecessary pinning have the effect of blocking security fixes in addition to feature upgrades? If so, it seems a really bad idea. Have to say, that my main distro blocks SNAP on openness grounds & I've uninstalled most of the flatpak software, so I couldn't run flatpak, even if I wanted to. Have you considered compiling software from source?

Comment: Kind of but I'm not good at it. With the pinning i block just the main package, no all the dependencies. And I normally pin software that is not important for the system.